# Is "avert" a valid term in Risk Management?

Tags: risk, definitions, management

I recently came across the term "avert" as an answer in a multiple choice question in an exam which has a module on risk management.

I am au fait with the terms "avoid", "mitigate", "transfer" and "accept". And I'm just wondering is this a synonym for "avoid" or "prevent" or is it just a "distractor" term which are all too common in MCQ formats.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a particularly common term (as you can see from [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=avert%20a%20risk,avoid%20a%20risk,prevent%20a%20risk) or [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avert+a+risk%2Cavoid+a+risk%2Cprevent+a+risk&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)) - but it certainly is used by some people.

It's a fairly clear phrase, so I don't think people would be confused by you using it. But whether it's considered "correct" in your contex will really come down to that individual exam board and the materiel that they're basing it on. It sounds to me like it's probably just a distraction (i.e, it sounds plausible, but isn't used in their training materiel) - but that's really just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen it in use for Risk and I actually find the term ambiguous.

**Avoid** is to put yourself into a position so that the hazard doesn't occur. You avoid the risk of ChatGPT by banning its use.

**Avert** is almost the same thing as "avoid" but it is more active. You avert the risk of ChatGPT by having training, policies, and technical controls.

So, linguistically, "avoid" and "avert" are nearly synonyms. But in a risk context, "avert" is closer to "mitigate"/"treat".

So, if you used the term in one of my risk meetings, I'd ask you to clarify what you meant.

My *guess* is that it was a distractor on the exam.

FYI: I'm also a fan of Tolerate, Treat, Transfer, and Terminate. Terminate and avert are very different terms.